# Merging two tables into one with the same column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I use this command to merge 2 tables into one:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS 
SELECT name, sum(cnt)
FROM (SELECT * FROM table2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table3) X
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY 1;
```

`table2` and `table3` are tables with columns named `name` and `cnt`, but the result table (`table1`) has the columns `name` and `sum`.

The question is how to change the command so that the result table will have the columns `name` and `cnt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of an explicit name, the output of a function inherits the basic function name in Postgres. You can use a column alias in the `SELECT` list to fix this - like [@hennes already supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25591922/939860).

If you need to inherit all original columns with name and type (and possibly more) you can also create the table with a separate command:

- To copy columns with names and data types only, still use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html), but add `LIMIT 0`:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE table1 AS
  TABLE table2 LIMIT 0;  -- "TABLE" is just shorthand for "SELECT * FROM"
  ```
- To copy ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)):

  > all column names, their data types, and their not-null constraints:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (LIKE table2);
  ```

  ... and *optionally* also defaults, constraints, indexes, comments and storage settings:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (LIKE table2 INCLUDING ALL);
  ```

  ... or, for instance, just defaults and constraints:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (LIKE table2 INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS);
  ```

Then `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, cnt)
SELECT ...        -- column names are ignored
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this (note the `AS cnt`)?

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT name,sum(cnt) AS cnt
  FROM ...
```