# Is it a bad practice to use a table only for multiple inheritance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-8.4

Modeling a PostgreSQL database, is it a bad practice to create a table to serve another tables? For example, create a table with default address fields.

```
CREATE TABLE address (
    zipcode char(8) NOT NULL,
    street varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    number varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    city varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    state char(2) NOT NULL
);
```

And then inherite it in every table which uses these fields. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(80)
) INHERITS (address);

CREATE TABLE company (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(80)
) INHERITS (address);

CREATE TABLE building (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(80)
) INHERITS (address);
```

The idea is apply something like [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in the tables creation proccess.

One of my main questions is if the table `address` can cause significative lose of performance because it will become each time bigger.

Comment: I would steer well clear of this; you could have quite a few issues with this - including if you have a *customer* who also works for the *company*. It may cause a few collisions if you're not too careful!

Comment: @jbutler483, In this case there isn't ploblem, PostgreSQL handle this situation easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the intention is to copy the table layout, the basic idea is fine, but **<strike>[inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html)</strike>** is a misunderstanding.

The idea to ***copy*** the table schema from another table is sound (if you really *need* a copy). But use

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE template_table);
```

Or

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE template_table INCLUDING ALL);
```

That's a *different*, built-in feature of the basic [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) statement. Copies the schema (with or without selected details), but the result is an *independant* table.
More details in this recent related answer:

- [Merging two tables into one with the same column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591824/merging-two-tables-into-one-with-the-same-column-names/25597446#25597446)

You can also *add columns* like in your examples with inheritance:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE template_table INCLUDING ALL, name text);
```

Comment: Glad to see you again, Erwin! Thanks for you suggestion! My intention was to propagate changes when they are made in `address` structure. But seems that `address` will become big and this can affect seriously the performance. Do you agree?

Comment: @MarcioSimao: Oh, if that's the intention, then go with **[normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)** and add foreign keys, like Craig already suggested. Inheritance would simply be the wrong tool for this.

Comment: I will go with normalization, thanks! I am using another technique that i am not sure if is a good practice, there is another question about it, could you please see it and tell me what you think? [The question can be accessed here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37226/will-table-inheritance-in-postgresql-suit-this-situation).

Comment: @MarcioSimao: Basically, study the [chapter about **caveats**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS) carefully, before you do anything with inheritance. If you don't find anything there, give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a good idea. Querying the `address` table will show you a bunch of jumbled addresses from all sources, but nothing to connect them to anything else usefully.

This would be better done with a conventional relational model via a foreign key reference to an address ID.

Another option is to define the address as a composite type and embed that in each table. You'll find that lots of client drivers don't like composite types very much, though, so it'll be clumsy to work with.

Really, stick with the simple relational approach here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will follow your suggestion. I am using another technique that i am not sure if is a good practice, there is another question about it, could you please see it and tell me what you think? [The question can be accessed here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37226/will-table-inheritance-in-postgresql-suit-this-situation).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Craig's answer on the technical merits, consider that it's also bad design: inheritance is used to signify "is-a" relationships. Your customer is **not** an address.

Your company may or may not have one or multiple addresses. This is a classical "has-a" relationship, which is what foreign keys were build for.

Comment: Nice additional comment, thanks! I am using another technique that i am not sure if is a good practice, there is another question about it, could you please see it and tell me what you think? [The question can be accessed here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37226/will-table-inheritance-in-postgresql-suit-this-situation).